# display in textbox when checkbox is checked in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

i have a checkbox in a gridview , i want to display row's data in textbox when i check o checkbox .this is my buttun's code  :

```
protected void ButtonModifEnfant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region
    try
    {
        int nbr_check = 0;
        string myid = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < gv_enfant.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant");
            if (check.Checked)
            {
                myid = ((HiddenField)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("codeenfant")).Value;

                //ButtonModifEnfant.Enabled = true;
                //ButtonSuppEnfant.Enabled = true;
                //myid = gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
                //nbr_check++;
            }
            else
            {
                //ButtonModifEnfant.Enabled = false;
                //ButtonSuppEnfant.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        if (nbr_check >= 1)
        {
            //ButtonModifEnfant.Enabled = true;
            Response.Write("<script>alert ('Error!')</script>");
            return;
        }
        else if (nbr_check == 1)
        {
            //ButtonModifEnfant.Enabled = true;
        }
        ModalPopupExtenderModifierEnfant.Show();
        c.cmd = c.cn.CreateCommand();
        c.cmd.CommandText = "select prenom , DateNaissance , Scolarise , Activite from  Enfants where codeEnfants = " + myid;
        if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            c.cn.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader read = c.cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.HasRows)
        {
            read.Read();
            TextBox_NPmodif.Text = read[0].ToString();
            TextBox_DNmodif.Text = read[1].ToString();
            TextBox_Scolarisemodif.Text = read[2].ToString();
            TextBox_Activitemodif.Text = read[3].ToString();
        }
        read.Close();
        //gv_enfant.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            c.cn.Close();
        }
    }
#endregion

}
```

and this is my checkbox code  :

```
    protected void CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int chek = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gv_enfant.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chbox = (CheckBox)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant");
            if (chbox.Checked)
            {
                chek++;
            }
        }
        if (chek != 1)
        {
            ButtonModifEnfant.Enabled = false;
            ButtonSuppEnfant.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonModifEnfant.Enabled = true;
            ButtonSuppEnfant.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

and for the html code of gridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_enfant" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    Width="533px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxenfant" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="codeenfant" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("codeEnfants") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prenom" HeaderText="prenom" SortExpression="prenom" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateNaissance" HeaderText="Date Naissance" DataFormatString="{0:d}"
            SortExpression="DateNaissance" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Scolarise" HeaderText="Scolarise" SortExpression="Scolarise" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Activite" HeaderText="Activite" SortExpression="Activite" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CVtechConnectionString10 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT *  FROM [Enfants] WHERE ([ppr] = @ppr)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="ppr" SessionField="code" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
if (check.Checked)
{

  txtBox.Text=gv_enfant["yourColumnName",i].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: which column value you want in the textBox??
Have you put above code inside your `for loop`. ??

Comment: this code that I have posed is the one i use now. in my textbox i want to display  these columns : " prenom , Datenaissance , Scolarise , activite" according to the column "codeEnfant"

Comment: It does'nt matter if a `column` is `visible` or `hidden` in `DataGridView` when you are accesing value by its `DataPropertyName`

Comment: " prenom , Datenaissance , Scolarise , activite". <-Are these Columns or Values

Answer (score 0):

try it,

**Front-End**

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxenfant" runat="server" index="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged"  />
 <asp:TextBox ID="textbx" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Eval("codeEnfants") %>' />
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte index = byte.Parse((s as CheckBox).Attributes["index"]);
            (gv_enfant.Rows[index].FindControl("textbx") as TextBox).Enabled = (gv_enfant.Rows[index].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant") as CheckBox).Checked;

        }
```

Comment: `protected void CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte index = byte.Parse((s as CheckBox).Attributes["index"]);
            (gv_enfant.Rows[index].FindControl("textbx") as TextBox).Enabled = (gv_enfant.Rows[index].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant") as CheckBox).Checked;

        }`

Comment: `protected void CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             
            byte index = byte.Parse((sender as CheckBox).Attributes["index"]);
            (gv_enfant.Rows[index].FindControl("textbx") as TextBox).Enabled = (gv_enfant.Rows[index].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant") as CheckBox).Checked;

        }`

Comment: `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxenfant" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxEnfants_CheckedChanged"  index='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="textbx" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Eval("codeEnfants") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: now there is no error but when i clik the button to display in textbox it does't work , no data is displayed in the textbox :(

Comment: Button click? I thought that CheckBox. Sorry i dont know storyboard in your application. But if you want to access any control in the grid's each row, useful code that shown above!

Comment: to show data in textbox i have to choose a row  using checkbox in gridview and click the button to display this row in these textbox.
i mentioned the code of the button above..

Comment: sorry for the disturbance